# How can I upload and edit images to a post? - Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I am building a blog app using Django and I would like the ability for users to add images to each post in a template. I have already added the image upload and everything works fine. The problem, however, is that the default Django image form (upload, edit and delete) doesn't look very pleasing and I am having too much difficulty customizing this. If anyone knows of a cabable and good looking solution or integration/service that works, please let me know.

Comment: How about [django-crispy-forms](https://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)?

Comment: @RobVezina Yeah, I have tried that, but it's not quite what I'm looking for.